# One of my MPLS link is not passing traffic

Tags: troubleshooting

I have two MPLS link and one is not passing traffic the other is passing traffic. What can be the cause of it.

Comment: Without any addition information, we won't be able to tell. Please provide configuration details, logs, details on what you've tried to debug this and any other relevant information.